# Java Rest api - Restrict concurrent requests of a user

Tags: java, mongodb, rest

I have a javax rest api which generates and downloads a PDF when called. It's a memory intensive call. I would like to restrict user to call it only once and don't allow concurrent requests to the API. If there is another request to the api by same user ,  it should not allow if there's already a request going on..  Though UI will restrict multiple clicks. , at the backend  I have to handle this case.

**My current backend solution :**

Whenever user hits the api , set a flag in mongoDB to `true`.  Once the response is given back (technically just before return statement), set the flag to `false`.  Check flag  before processing every request.

something like

```
if(mongoDB.getCurrentUserFlag()) { //request is on-going. Don't allow.}
else
// go ahead
```

I would like to know if there's a optimal and better approach.

Comment: Have you considered some clean-up? Should all user flags be set to false when the application starts?

Comment: yes.. that's taken care..  i am more worried if due to any reason the flag updation fails and user cannot fire the api at all..    Also looking for any better approach ..